# how process auto click with material angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like use layout tabs material with Angular:

https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

I would like use auto click, how I do it ? how ask angular to click link "Tab1" wait 3 seconds and click"Tab2" in the loop.

Comment: please search for the javascript function `setInterval()`

Comment: Thank's for response,

Comment: before use setInterval(), i search how i can automatic self click the link tap1 and tab2, I am noobe , in the jquery i know how dot it , but with material i did not how i can't do it

Comment: no problem, the issue you are facing is then quite simple, even if someone gave you the answer bellow, you should learn to read the api doc especially this part: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the `selectedIndex` property of the `<mat-tab-group>` like so:

html:

```
<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

component:

```
selectedIndex = 0;
...

    ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.selectNextTab();
        }, 3000);
    }

    selectNextTab() {
        this.selectedIndex++;
    }
...
```

Comment: Thank for help with [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex" ,,  you snippet is walk :)